# How to write ASCII 026 char on iPhone

Tags: character, ascii, substitution

I have a customer on a webshop, who has managed to write her last name as 195 131 026 082 110 116 111 102 116 013 010 (ÃRntoft), which is breaking stuff.

The character 026 ("Substitute"), is my problem.
How is it possible to produce this character on an iPhone?
What does the char represent in an iPhone context?

Comment: 195 > 127 ⇒ not ASCII. 195 131 is 0xC3 0x83 is UTF-8 for [Ã](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&names=-&utf8=0x). Perhaps you have one or more broken conversions going one, particularly since you are call UTF-8 ASCII.

Comment: Who cares if I call it an ASCII char or not? Your comment is a waste of your and my time.